# What is the characteristic of fields quasi real-closed fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that $F$ is a field such that $F^*$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of a real-closed field.

I researched about these fields and I found that they can have $Char(F)=p>2$, but it is impossible that $Char(F)=2$.

I want the reason of it, i.e why $Char(F)\neq 2$.

Comment: Think about $2^n$-th powers.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Can you explain your answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear because we should have $-1\neq 1$ and in $Char=2$ we have $-1=1$ a contradiction.